# Converting SQL to LINQ using MAX

Tags: c#, sql, linq, max

I have two tables

**1)** T_EJV_CREDIT_DS_INDEX 
**2)** T_EJV_CREDIT_DS_INDEX_CONTRACT

[image]

I would like a SQL query like below as a LINQ expression

```
SELECT MAX(INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION) FROM T_EJV_CREDIT_DS_INDEX cdi
INNER JOIN T_EJV_CREDIT_DS_INDEX_CONTRACT cdic
ON cdic.INDEX_ID = cdi.INDEX_ID
WHERE cdi.INDEX_SHORT_NAME LIKE '%@VARIABLE1%'
AND cdic.TENOR = @VARIABLE2
```

This is what I have attempted so far

```
var maxFamilyVersion = (from ic in dsIndexContract
                       join i in dsIndex on i.INDEX_ID equals ic.INDEX_ID
                       where i.INDEX_SHORT_NAME.CONTAINS(strindex) && ic.TENOR equals d.TERM 
                       select new
                       {
                           ic.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION.Max()     
                       }).Take(1).ToList();
```

But the above mentioned starts showing compile issues with the syantax as shown below

[image]

Comment: the nice thing about visual studio is it puts a red squiggle where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var maxFamilyVersion = 
                 (from ic in dsIndexContract
                 join i in dsIndex on ic.INDEX_ID equals i.INDEX_ID
                 where i.INDEX_SHORT_NAME.CONTAINS(strindex) && ic.TENOR == d.TERM 
                 select ic.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION).Max();
```

Comment: var maxFamilyVersion =
                 (from ic in dsIndexContract
                  join i in dsIndex on ic.INDEX_ID equals i.INDEX_ID                  where i.INDEX_SHORT_NAME.Contains(strindex) && ic.TENOR == d.TERM
                  select i.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION).Max();

Did a tweak and it started working thanks

Answer (score 2):

Checking for equality in your where condition can be done with **==**. The keyword `equals` is only used in a join condition.

```
  var result = (from ic in dsIndexContract
                join i in dsIndex on i.INDEX_ID equals ic.INDEX_ID
                where i.INDEX_SHORT_NAME.CONTAINS(strindex) && ic.TENOR == d.TERM 
                select new
                {
                    ic.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION.Max()     
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

And instead of `.Take(1).ToList()`, you can use `.FirstOrDefault()` to retrieve the first item.

Or a more efficient way is to use `.Max()` directly instead of `.FirstOrDefault()`:

```
  var result = (from ic in dsIndexContract
                    join i in dsIndex on i.INDEX_ID equals ic.INDEX_ID
                    where i.INDEX_SHORT_NAME.CONTAINS(strindex) && ic.TENOR == d.TERM 
                    select ic.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION).Max();
```

Comment: var result = (from ic in dsIndexContract  
                              join i in dsIndex on ic.INDEX_ID equals i.INDEX_ID                                where i.INDEX_SHORT_NAME.Contains(strindex) && ic.TENOR ==  d.TERM                                select i.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION).Max();

Comment: @Loetn You can do `Max` on a column like `ic.INDEX_FAMILY_VERSION.Max() ` since it is not a collection.

Comment: @Magnus Yeah, I know, my bad. I will change it.